# Stopping a background Task

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How can I stop an already running background task without the user going to the UI of my application?

Comment: Have you tried to: cancel all *Tasks*, unregister the BTask, call deferal.Complete() and return?

Comment: I could do all of that from the UI thread of the application. However, I'm trying to stop the background Task under a certain condition from the background task which I'm trying to stop. Also I don't want the backgroundTask to be unregistered.
I'm using `deferal.Complete()` under a conditional statementbut I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Comment: Everything depends on your BackgroundTask - what do you have in your *Run* method. If it's synchronous then you don't need deferal - simple *return* would be sufficient. On the other hand if you have asynchronous BackgroundTask and/or use additional threads, you should get deferal and when you finish your work (or cancel), call deferal.complere(). Tomorrow I'll try to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *BackgroundTask* is synchronous, then you need just to leave the *Run* method to finish with the task.

If you have *asynchronous BackgroundTask*, you need to use [BackgroundTaskDeferral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskdeferral.aspx) - obtain at the beginning and call *Complete()* once you finish your work. As it's said [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx):

> 4. If you run any asynchronous code in your background task, then your background task needs to use a deferral. If you don't use a deferral, then the background task process can terminate unexpectedly if the Run method completes before your asynchronous method call has completed.

You should be also aware that the OS can terminate your task earlier - if the task exceeded [the limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) or trigger condition is no longer fulfilled - for example [MaintenanceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj883699.aspx).

When you finish with *asynchronous BackgroundTask*, pay attention to finish/cancel all *Tasks*, you may need to implement [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx).